# How to show sql results under titles on python / pymysql?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, pymysql

```
def selectTopNactors(n):

# Create a new connection
con=connection()

# Create a cursor on the connection
cur=con.cursor()
#execute query
sql ="""SELECT g.genre_name AS 'genreName', a.actor_id AS 'actorId', COUNT(*) AS 'number_of_movies'
FROM actor AS a, role AS r, movie AS m, genre AS g, movie_has_genre AS mg
WHERE a.actor_id = r.actor_id AND m.movie_id = r.movie_id
    AND m.movie_id = mg.movie_id AND g.genre_id = mg.genre_id
    AND (g.genre_id , m.movie_id) IN (SELECT g.genre_id, m.movie_id
                                        FROM movie AS m, genre AS g, movie_has_genre AS mg
                                        WHERE m.movie_id = mg.movie_id AND mg.genre_id = g.genre_id
                                        ORDER BY g.genre_id)
GROUP BY a.actor_id,g.genre_name

ORDER BY g.genre_name,number_of_movies DESC LIMIT 5 """

cur.execute(sql,)
results = cur.fetchall()
for row in cur:
     #genre_name = row[0]
     #actor_id = row[1]
     #number_of_movies = row[2]
     print(row["g.genre_id"])
     print(row["a.actor_id"])
     print(row["number_of_movies"])



print (n)
con.commit()
return [("genreName ", "actorId ", "numberOfMovies"),results]
```

When I try this I get something like this :

[image: Result]

But I want every result to be showed in each column, for example actorid's in column of actorid and genre names in the column of genreName etc.

Comment: I have no idea how to address the front-end problem since you don't show any code but your query is returning tuples. This is normal. You just chose to throw that to the front-end.

Comment: In other words, I don't think it's possible to answer this without the front-end code. You either make a decision on how you're going to send the data, or how the front-end processes that data. In reality, both decisions are important, but your question only gives half the story.

Comment: That is unless I've completely misunderstood your screenshot, but it looks like it's custom to your data

Comment: @roganjosh sorry for the bad link I just created a new file on dropbox, I have shared all the files here : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3sast48wjc6h5yp/AAAHJb81SrZqNjoD1NTnZAwPa?dl=0

Comment: The link you've posted me doesn't make sense (it actually barely loads for me) but that's not the point I was making. I'm saying that the original screenshot (which should be embedded into the question) looks like a customised dashboard... then all my comments apply. But maybe it's something built in to mysql in particular, which is where I would be wrong.